# How could I access the Moodle course usage statistics?

Tags: mysql, moodle

There's the possibility to view the course usage statistics / course activity. So I'm able to see which file was clicked how many times by how many students. (Data is anonymized)
I have problems figuring out, where the data is saved. Also I couldn't any useful hint in the moodle docs.

Is there any MySQL table where the data is saved?

EDIT: I try to kind of develop a plugin which displays the activity data as graphs. Therefore I try to find where the data is saved. (I have access to the db because I use a local installation of Moodle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `logstore_standard_log` table. This is where user logs are stored in.

Comment: There is saved e.g. which user id accessed which course or which user logged in. I need the db which saves the data for the report about the activity. So hard to explain. The Moodle Docs and Structure is complicated imo

Comment: I would say you could find the user activity from the `logstore_standard_log` table as the user actions are stored there. For instance if you need to find how many times the course module with id 9 was accessed by a user you would use something like `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE userid=[USERID] AND target="course_module" AND objectid=9`

Comment: That's sounds very good. I didn't see that. So objectid=9 would be the id of the file?

Comment: Activity URLs in Moodle look like `www.example.com/mod/ACTIVITY_NAME/view.php?id=ACTIVITY_ID`, so for the "file" activity you would have something like `www.example.com/mod/resource/view.php?id=9`, where `9` is the id of the activity in the `course_modules` table. The `objectid` from the `logstore_standard_log` table represents the record id of the table specified in the `objecttable` column. So, if the `objecttable = course_modules`, you would look in the `course_modules` table for that id to get the relevant data, if `objecttable = user` you would look in the `user` table etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. FYI: the report of the activity is a plugin saved in `/moodle/report/outline`